# How do I turn a @Query into a publisher in SwiftData

Tags: swift

My view is using @Query which is updating very rapidly.

I'd like to throttle it. I assumed it could be reasonable to use a Combine throttle but it doesn't seem to have a way to do that.

Example:

```
struct MyView: View {

@Query(descriptor()) var data: [Data]

var body: some View {

    Text(data?.last.value ?? "NA") // last and first are same, should have single element per the descriptor
}

}

// I want the last item added
// the data is written at 10 items per second
// For my needs it suffices to get the item once per second at most
func descriptor() {
   var descriptor = FetchDescriptor<Data>(sortBy: [SortDescriptor(\.eventTime, orderReverse)])
   descriptor.fetchLimit = 1
   return descriptor
}
```

what I want:

```
data.publisher.throttled(1 second)
```

Comment: You would have to create your own. Since it is a single item maybe TimelineView and a manual fetch.

Comment: Maybe use a timer to call the FetchDescriptor directly.